# Python Code for Halley's Method returns error for a given precision

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for [Halley's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) to solve the [Kepler's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation).

The initial approximation of x is M and I have to find the number of iterations needed till the desired precision of 10e-12 is reached.

The code is as follows:

```
h = 0.000000000001

import numpy as np

eps = 0.0000000000001
e = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
M = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

def f(x):
    return x - e*np.sin(x) - M

def fp(x):
    global h
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h

def fpp(x):
    global h
    return (fp(x + h) - fp(x)) / h

x = M

while True:
    fx = f(x)
    fpx = fp(x)
    xnew = x - (2.0 * fx * fpx) / (2.0 * fpx * fpx - fx * fpp(x))
    print (xnew)
    if abs(xnew - x) >= eps: break
    x = xnew
```

This returns an error:

> if abs(xnew - x) >= eps: break
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I also am not understanding how to find out the number of iterations inside the while loop till the desired accuracy is reached

Comment: You're getting this error because x is an array and you are comparing it to eps which is a scalar and expecting this to evaluate to either True or False, but there is no obvious way for Python to interpret this request. What were you expecting that line to do? Did you intend to aggregate x in some way, or was assigning x=M a mistake?

Comment: @SimonN I understand my mistake now thanks. x = M is the initial value of x which is needed to begin the iterative solving process. I want to stop the iteration when (xnew - x) value reaches a particular precision which is denoted by the variable eps.